# C# serial port integration issues with read

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hello I have a question what could be optimized for my code because for some reasons I need to increase read timeout values for serial port even tho in C++ the timeouts were even smaller and it worked fine. The C++ timeouts were 250ms and now they need to be 3000ms the code I am having troubles with is this is there a way i have made any problems in these methods? the receive method is just a normal read command that waits for binary response and then checks it, and I am sending the command every 1ms for maximum responses:

```
public virtual void SendSyncCommand(ISerialCommand queryCommand, ISerialCommand responseCommand)
    {
      _ = queryCommand ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryCommand), $"{nameof(queryCommand)} cannot be null!");
      _ = responseCommand ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(responseCommand), $"{nameof(responseCommand)} cannot be null!");

      try
      {
        bool success = false;
        int tryCount = 0;

        commandMutex.Wait();

        if(!IsConnected)
        {
          throw new DeviceException("Device is not connected");
        }

        while (!success)
        {
          tryCount++;

          string sentData = string.Empty;
          string receivedData = string.Empty;

          try
          {
            // send command
            Logger.Debug($"Request command: {queryCommand.GetType().Name} ({queryCommand.ToString()}).");
            Console.WriteLine(queryCommand.ToString());
            queryCommand.Execute(this, out sentData);

            // receive reply
            responseCommand.Receive(this, out receivedData);
            Logger.Debug($"Response command: {responseCommand.GetType().Name} ({receivedData})");

            success = true;
          }
          catch (Exception exception) when (!(exception is OperationCanceledException))
          {
            ClearBuffer();
            
            var logMessage = $"Error while communicating with the device: {exception.GetType().Name} (Sent data: [{ToHexString(sentData)}] <> Received data: [{ToHexString(receivedData)}]).";

            if (tryCount <= RetryCount) // equality to account for initial try
            {
              Logger.Warn(logMessage);
              Logger.Debug(exception.Message);
              Thread.Sleep(100); // wait before sending a new packet
            }
            else
            {
              Logger.Error(logMessage);
              Logger.Debug(exception.Message);
              throw;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        commandMutex.Release();
      }
    }

 public virtual bool Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
      if (count > bufferSize)
      {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), $"Cannot read more than {bufferSize} bytes.");
      }

      try
      {
        connectionMutex.Wait();

        var stream = GetStream();

        if (stream is null)
        {
          return false;
        }

        if (this.offset < count)
        {
          var bytesRead = stream.Read(this.buffer, this.offset, count - this.offset);

          if (bytesRead == 0) // couldn't read any bytes, skip
          {
            throw new DeviceException("Could not read data from device connection stream.");
          }

          this.offset += bytesRead;
        }

        Array.Copy(this.buffer, 0, buffer, offset, count);

        var bytesToCopy = this.offset - count;
        Array.Copy(this.buffer, count, this.buffer, 0, bytesToCopy);
        this.offset = bytesToCopy;

        return true;
      }
      catch(Exception ex) when (ex is IOException || ex is TimeoutException || ex is InvalidOperationException)
      {
        throw new DeviceException("Failed to read data from device connection stream.", ex);
      }
      finally
      {
        connectionMutex.Release();
      }
    }
```

after read timeouts it starts receiving information in stable fashion but this doesn't work for my solution

Regarding to comment I am providing the ReadData function:

```
    public override string ReadData(IConnection connection, out string message)
    {
      if (connection == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connection));
      }


      Header header = new Header();
      byte[] headerBytesTmp = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Header))];
      message = "";
      try
      {
        connection.Read(headerBytesTmp, 0, headerBytesTmp.Length);
        GCHandle headerHandleTmp = GCHandle.Alloc(headerBytesTmp, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        header = ByteArrayToHeader(headerBytesTmp);
        headerHandleTmp.Free();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        // Handle exception
        throw new Exception("Error receiving command header: " + ex.Message);
      }

      message = BitConverter.ToString(headerBytesTmp).Replace("-", "");
      if (header.StartSequence.ToString("X") != HeaderStartSequence)
      {
        throw new PolarisException("Unexpected response to BX command: [" + message + "]");
      }

      if (!RemoveCRCHex(message))
      {
        // Handle error
        SpectraSpatialTracker.logger.Error("Header dump:[" + message + "]");
        throw new Exception("invalid header crc");
      }

      uint length = (uint)header.ReplyLength + 2; // 2 - space for CRC
      byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

      try
      {
        connection.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        // Handle exception
        throw new Exception("Error receiving command body: " + ex.Message);
      }

      message += BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "");
      return message;
    }
```

ReadTimeout settings in C#

```
 protected override void ConnectDevice()
    {
      if(!IsConnected)
      {
        client = new SerialPort($"COM{PortNo}", ComParameters.BaudRate, ComParameters.Parity, ComParameters.DataBits, ComParameters.StopBits)
        {
          ReadTimeout = RS232Timeouts.ReadTimeout,
          WriteTimeout = RS232Timeouts.WriteTimeout
        };
        client.Open();

        Logger.Debug($"Connected to COM{PortNo} using RS232 interface.");
      }
    }
```

in C++

````
RS232Timeouts(unsigned int readInterval = 10, 
          unsigned int readTotalMult = 0, 
          unsigned int readTotalConst = 0, 
          unsigned int writeTotalMult = 0, 
          unsigned int writeTotalConst = 5000)


void RS232DeviceConnection::SetTimeouts(const RS232Timeouts& timeouts)
{
  mTimeouts = timeouts;
  if( mStream.IsOpen())
  {
    mStream << mTimeouts;
  }
}
    ```
````

Comment: So, you expect responses every 1ms, but you get responses with more than 250ms interval? If you use a request-response-model, how do you ensure you are not starting to read before making a request? If there is only problems at startup it sounds like some kind of timing or synchronization issue.

Comment: Sorry if i stated incorrectly. I am trying to send and get response every MS, but i am locking the operation and waiting for it to finish. and only after that i am letting to start another one. Basically need to send command then read first 6 bytes, 3rd and 4th bytes tells me the full length of the response.  and i read again from the same buffer and that's it. but the problem occurs in about 5 min because after something around the time if the SerialPort read timeout is set to 250 as was in c++ i get the empty response if I increase the timeout to 3 seconds the response will always be there.

Comment: The OS serial port API which your C++ code probably used provides access to all three read timeout settings, but the .NET SerialPort class assumes you only need one of them (which is a very poor assumption).  Show the C++ code that sets the timeouts.

Comment: i have updated the question with C# and C++ timeouts, but i am not sure it will help in any way